# Should every instance of application have their own cassandra session or they should share the same session?

Tags: python, cassandra

I have a cluster setup of 3 nodes.

I am designing my microservice and I am wondering if each node should have their own Cassandra session or if all three should share the same session created by any of the nodes.

I have read in the Cassandra docs:

> "The Session instance is a long-lived object and it should not be used
>   in a request/response short-lived fashion. Basically you will want to
>   share the same cluster and session instances across your application."

What does this mean?

Comment: How would you share the session between multiple processes (maybe even hosts)?

Comment: i dont know, is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

You share your session on application level. Different applications should have own sessions.

Your quote means that you dont open a session for a query but rather have a singleton Session instance in your application.

Comment: So if 3 instance of application is running on 3 hosts, each one should have single copy of session of their own, right??